# a question on time, distance and speed

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ram and Gopi run towards each other starting from K and L respectively with respective speeds of 2 kmph and 3 kmph. After meeting each other, to reach L, if Ram takes 7 hours less than the square of magnitude of the time (in hours) taken by Gopi to reach K, find the distance between K and L.

A. 25 km
B. 28 km
C. 30 km
D. 32 km

well, looking at their speeds and assuming the time taken to meet be "x", the total distance comes out to be 2x + 3x = 5x. so I know the answer is either A or C. but after that I cannot form an equation or figure out their time.

Comment: Your last two questions were closed. Please tell us a bit about what you have tried in solving this problem, otherwise this question might just get closed as well.

Comment: well, looking at their speeds and assuming the time taken to meet be "x", the total distance comes out to be 2x + 3x = 5x. so I know the answer is either A or C. but after that I cannot form an equation or figure out their time.

Comment: Great. Now edit this comment into the question itself. And when you ask new questions in the future, always include what you have tried in the question itself.

Comment: are the tags correct for this type of question?

Comment: Good. I have retracted my close vote and my downvote.

Comment: The logic tag seems off. But the algebra-precalculus tag is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  let the distance from $K$ to $L$ be $d$.  What is the distance from $K$ to the meeting point?  What is the distance from the meeting point to $L$?  How long does it take Gopi to reach $K$ after they meet?  Plug this into the equation indicated by "if Ram takes..." and you will have an equation for $d$.

Comment: I proceeded with the idea but didn't arrive at anything given in the option.
the equation I got was 8x^2 - 27x - 126. Solving, I got 12. and resolving for the answer gives me 60

Comment: @vickyace: Please show your steps getting the equation.  I did it in terms of $d$.  After the meeting, $G$ takes $\frac {2d}{15}$ to finish and $R$ takes $\frac {3d}{10}$, so $(\frac {2d}{15})^2-7=\frac {3d}{10}$

Comment: let the time taken to meet be "x." then total distance travelled by R and G in x hours at the speed of 2 and 3 kmph respectively will be 2x and 3x. adding them up gives us 5x, which is the total distance. after the meet, R has to go a distance of 3x (the distance covered by G during x hours) and similarly G has to travel 2x, which was covered by R. so the the time equation becomes, 3x/2 = (2x/3)^2 - 7. which gives 8x^2 - 27x - 126.

sorry for the late reply.

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%2F2%3D4x%5E2%2F9-7) or [your version](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8x%5E2-27x%3D126) solves the equation getting $x=6$, so the distance is $30$.  You must have an error solving the equation.

Answer (score 0):

As per question , and your 1st step solution, 
3x/2 + 7 = (2x/3)^2 = 4x^2 /9
27x + 126 = 8x^2 
8x^2- 27x -126 = 0 
(8x + 21)*(x -6)=0
so x =6 (as x can not be negative so x = -21/8 is not possible)
required distance = 5x = 30 km

for more such concept :https://www.handakafunda.com/motion-of-two-bodies-in-a-straight-line/